# Nginx rewrite rule (subdirectory to subdomain)

Tags: nginx

I would like to redirect admin subdirectory to a subdomain. I tried to create this rule for Nginx however it's not working:

```
location ^~ /admin/ {
        rewrite ^/admin(.*) http://admin.example.com$uri permanent;
     }
```

Thank you
Regards

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Something like this should do the job:

```
location ^~ /admin/ {
    rewrite ^/admin/(.*) $scheme://admin.example.com/$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply.  I've changed a bit to optimize it:
    `rewrite ^ http://admin.example.com/login.php$1 permanent;`. I would like to also set another redirection from `http://admin.exmaple.com` to `http://admin.example.com/login.php`. Do I have to set another "location" or there is any better way to achive this. Will this cause any loops?. Thank you

Comment: You should use $scheme instead of http:// since you can later use https. 
`rewrite ^/admin/(.*) $scheme://admin.example.com/$1 permanent;` 
See: http://nginx.org/en/docs/varindex.html?_ga=1.117673482.204797739.1489752542